# Adding edit photo page to django image gallery app using Python

Tags: python, html, django

I have an image gallery app in Django that has an upload image page and sends that photo to a gallery page. Also, there's an edit photo page where I want to display the uploaded image and edit it, then submit the edited photo to the gallery page. How can I have the currently uploaded image show up on both the upload image and edit pages?

`views.py` #uploads form for add image page(named `addartifact`)

```
def addartifact(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = EditorForm()
        return render(request=request,template_name='addartifact.html', context={'form': form})

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            imgtitle = form.cleaned_data['imgtitle']
            imgdesc = form.cleaned_data['imgdesc']
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            artifact = Artifact.objects.create(imgtitle=imgtitle, imgdesc=imgdesc, image=image)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('landingpage'))
```

`views.py` #uploads image to page

```
def image_upload_view(request):
    """Process images uploaded by users"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Get the current instance object to display in the template
            img_obj = form.instance
            return render(request, 'addartifact.html', {'form': form, 'img_obj': img_obj})
            
    else:
        form = ImageForm()
    return render(request, 'addartifact.html', {'form': form})
```

`forms.py`

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form for the image model"""
    class Meta:
        model = Artifact
        fields = ('artifact_id', 'imgtitle', 'imgdesc', 'image')

class EditorForm(forms.Form):
    imgtitle = forms.CharField(max_length=13, required=True, label=False,      widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'style': 'text-transform:lowercase;', 'placeholder': 'enter title'}))

    imgdesc = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'add description'}), label=False, required=True)

    image = forms.URLField(required=True, label=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'add image'}))
```

`models.py`

```
class Artifact(models.Model):
    artifact_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    imgtitle = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    imgdesc = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
       ordering = ['-created_at']
```

Comment: You probably want a separate view for edit. Then from a list of images or a specific image, you can click a link that relates to a specific image that contains a unique identifier for that image you want to edit. That way the view knows what to retrieve from the database for editing.

Comment: Thanks for the edits and response, I have a created_at field in models.py, would that be a reasonable identifier to display last image created for editing?

Comment: You'd need something unique, so the database ID or a column that you specify as a unique field. Otherwise you may end up unable to edit the object you want because the value is shared between multiple objects.